# PvZ Zen garden snail money making exploit on iPhone

Tags: ios, plants-vs-zombies

[This page on IGN](https://www.ign.com/wikis/plants-vs-zombies/IPad_Cheats) about *Plants vs Zombies iPad Cheats* says:

> Go to your Zen Garden when most or all plants need watering.  Once they are all watered and gleaming, give Stinky chocolate and then leave Zen Garden.  Come back to the Zen Garden after playing a bunch of games, or just come back 5, 10, 30 minutes later.  You must enter the Zen Garden from the Main Menu.  Once you enter the Zen Garden, it'll state that Stinky earned you (X) amount of gold.  Gently swipe a short distance from the top of the screen, but not more than a few centimeters.  Repeat this slowly, but regularly.  You'll notice the amounts Stinky collected for you constantly changes and your coin amounts increasing.  If Stinky is asleep or goes to sleep, do not wake him.  just continue swiping, and DON'T collect any coins that pop up.

Is this a real exploit?

I can't figure out what this part means:

> Gently swipe a short distance from the top of the screen, but not more than a few centimeters

So my question is, does such a money-making exploit exist in the Zen garden in the iOS version of Plants vs Zombies?

Comment: I'd say this would likely be hard to answer for several reasons - firstly, the page was last updated 5 years ago. Secondly, the app itself has been changed, updated and changed again for several reasons, and there is no way to know which version this "glitch" might apply to, and ultimately the device difference could also affect this glitch as well - iPads function differently to iPhones, and the version of the device itself also affects its functionality.